# Bootstrap Jumbotron background image does not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added a jumbotron to my website and I'm trying to change its background image but it doesn't work. I'm 100% positive that the image path is correct.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url("images/aezakmi.jpg"); background-size: contain;">
  <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your path is fine but your quotes are wrong. Use `url('images/aezakmi.jpg')`. Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo

Comment: Thanks a lot kind Sir !

Answer (score 0):

I'm still sort of new to HTML, but if I recall correctly, usually the url() method doesn't need quotes. Try it with an actual HTTP url with and without the quotes and see which works. If it still doesn't work, try moving your image to a new directory, or simply, upload it to imgur or something so you can grab it with an HTTP url.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can think of that would cause that is if you have the link to the image wrong or if you haven't made the link to your .css file correctly.